# How to make a user input both a string and integer

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a game that is kind of along the lines of the game mastermind.
I have a section where the user has to either guess the number or type "exit" to stop the game. How do i make it so that the code allows both an integer and string input?
The code is:

```
PlayerNum = int(input("Type your number in here:"))
if PlayerNum == "exit":
    print "The number was:",RandNum1,RandNum2,RandNum3,RandNum4
    print "Thanks for playing!
    exit()
```

If anyone could help that would be great.
Thanks. :D

Comment: `PlayerNum.isalpha()`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use isdigit() function to check whether input is int or string.

Let user has input "32" then "32".isdigit() will return True but if user has input "exit" then "exit".isdigit() will return False.

```
player_input = input("enter the number")
if player_input.isdigit():
   # Do stuff for integer
else:
   # Do stuff for string
```

Comment: Thanks for the help  :D

Answer (score 0):

```
PlayerNum = input("Type your number in here:")
```

Well You can remove the int so that it takes both integet and string as input

Answer (score 0):

Integer and String classifications are specific to Python (they are functions). When the user types in their response, that would be interpreted by the system as stdin (standard input).

Once the stdin is entered by the user and allocated under the PlayerNum variable, you are free to convert it to an int/str/bytes as you please.